# Two (any) areas in canvas: figuring out which is bigger

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, easeljs

I recently started learning canvas+easeljs together and at the moment I'm working on a 2D game. 
Player (small red rectangle) can move across the canvas, and when he is "out" (not next to the) of the border, the line is being drawn behind him.

When he comes to the next border, line stops drawing itself - which creates two areas separated by this line.

At this point, I need to figure out how big each area is in comparison to the other.

So what I need to figure out is:

- which area is smaller/bigger
- count the balls (small red circle) in each area

The grid that is drawn behind is there just to make it easier to understand what the logic behind UI is: zeroes represent blank spaces (white rectangles), twos represent gray rectangles (border and our line).

I tried counting zeroes in each area by "for looping" through whole canvas, but that didn't go very well since you need to carefully switch between each area.

Is there a better way do figure this out? Maybe by doing it recursively somehow?

[image: The two areas I need to use]

If I was not clear enough, please don't hesitate to ask for more info. 
And sorry for bad Title, I don't know how to put it to be more clear.

Looking forward to any suggestions, thanks!

EDIT1: the game is similar to this one: http://xonix.vamplabs.com

Comment: Please share the code you have problems with.

Comment: I don't really have problems with any specific line or something - i'm just not sure what approach to take. And the code at the moment is at 500+ lines, so it wouldn't be very useful to post it probably.

Comment: Could you explain your game better.  So the player is somehow creating barrier walls as they move?

Comment: @markE Correct. He creates a wall behind him, so now the ball is able to move only in one of the areas that are created by this wall. And each time he creates a wall, I have to figure out which wall is bigger/smaller and if it contains a ball or not. The game is gonna be similar to this one http://xonix.vamplabs.com Edited question also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible but fairly ineffective approach:

- Invert your representation for easier understanding. Let grey cells be 0 and white cells be 1.
- Trigger area identification when player comes back to the border. Make a temporary copy of the game field. Iterate through the whole field until you find a cell with a 1. Start calculating the size: (remember to make all value changes on the copied field!)
- Here you can try a recursive approach. Select the "1" cell and add 1 to a counter variable. Swap the cell to a 0 and take a look at any neighbouring cell. Branch out recursively for any cell that has the value "1".
- What happens now is you started in one of your AREAs and start to fill up the AREA with "walls", while remembering how many fields you filled. Due to branching out from the border you should hit any contained field by progressing to neighbors, without leaving the area boundaries.
- When the area is "finished" (all fields turned to 0, all recursive branches returned), your counter variable represents the size of the area. You can also check for your red balls while iterating through the area in the previous steps to count them.
- To go to the next AREA, just start iterating over the whole field again until you hit a 1, and repeat the previous steps.
- When you iterate over the whole field and didn't find any 1, you evaluated all areas and are finished.

As warned, terribly ineffective, but I can't think of a better way right now without running into complicated corner cases...

---

**UPDATE** for clarifications, see comments to this answer for reference.

Pseudo-code for recursive cell evaluation of one area:

```
int areaSize = 0;
//find the first starter cell to detect first area
Cell starter = findCellWithValue1();
//if starter is null, no cell with value 1 has been found
if( starter != null ) {
   //feed the starter cell into the recursive function
   areaSize = evaluateCell(starter);
}

int evaluateCell(Cell selected) {
    //counter variable to accumulate branched values
    int counter = 1;
    //set this cell to 0 to not hit it again when evaluating neighbours
    selected.setValue(0);

    //check neighbour to the left
    Cell neighbour = getCellAt(selected.getX()-1, selected.getY());
    if(neighbour.getValue()==1) {
        counter += evaluateCell(neighbour);
    }
    //check neighbour to the right
    neighbour = getCellAt(selected.getX()+1, selected.getY());
    if(neighbour.getValue()==1) {
        counter += evaluateCell(neighbour);
    }
    //check top neighbour
    neighbour = getCellAt(selected.getX(), selected.getY()+1);
    if(neighbour.getValue()==1) {
        counter += evaluateCell(neighbour);
    }
    //check bottom neighbour
    neighbour = getCellAt(selected.getX(), selected.getY()-1);
    if(neighbour.getValue()==1) {
        counter += evaluateCell(neighbour);
    }

    //return accumulated size
    return counter;
}
```

This will perform quite a lot of ultimately unnecessary checks, but I don't think they are too expensive unless you plan to have a giant playfield.

The final size of the area would be the content of the areaSize variable.

Comment: The problem is, how do you know you came to the second area? The line you make, can go anywhere before it reaches the "border". So it can be weird to figure this out, its's not always a rectangular - and even if it would be, how do you know you came to Area 2 ? sorry i'm a bit puzzled here

Comment: 1st: Areas can be of any shape with the proposed algorithm, as long as the white fields of a area are all touching on at least on side.

2nd: You dont "come" to a second area while evaluating one. Your areas are all surrounded by 0's, so when you jump from 1 to 1 while evaluating an area you would never overstep this surrounding border. You would only get to a second area when you deleted the first area on your copied field, and then start searching for any other area again.

Comment: Will try to implement what you proposed today and let you know -

Comment: Ok, I have a problem with your algorithm. This part where you get to "1" cell -> "and take a look at any neighbouring cell. Branch out recursively for any cell that has the value "1"." -> How to look at neighbouring cell? You want to check ALL the neighbours each time?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise you will miss out on corner cases. I'll update my answer with a little pseudocode.

Comment: Hey! I managed to count how big each area is recursively, it wasn't all the hard actually! I didn't use a copy of the whole field, but did use your approach otherwise. (i left numbers as they were - wanted to try it asap :D ) Now I have a new problem - a border that the player created, is now drawn over everything, so the player is not seen when moving on the new border. Do you know anything about layering here? But I guess that is a new question already, will accept yours now :) thank you

Comment: The one problem left with this question here is: how to save one definite starting point (indeces) of BOTH area-s, so I can decide later on which area I want to perform something … For the first area, it's trivial: save the index where you found first "blank" spot. What about the second area?
EDIT: I know - there your second "canvas" comes in handy. And your second count after the first. its time/resource consuming but it will work yeah. you were correct sir. Thanks again (sorry for thinking aloud :D )

Comment: You're welcome. No doubt there's a better way to do it, but that heavily depends on your data structures and tools in use.